How can I detect that a scriptblock is bound to the SessionState of another Runspace?
Consider the following code
foreach ($i in 1..100) {
    $sb = {'bound_to_parent_runspace'}
    . $sb | Out-Null

    1..2 |
        ForEach-Object {
            Start-ThreadJob `
                -ArgumentList ([pscustomobject]@{ScriptBlock = $sb}) `
                -ScriptBlock {
                    param($arg1)
                    'child_runspace'
                    . $arg1.ScriptBlock
                }                     |
                Receive-Job           `
                    -Wait             `
                    -ErrorAction Stop
        }
}

which occasionally (at least on my computer) causes the fatal error
An error has occurred that was not properly handled. Additional information is shown below. The PowerShell process will exit.
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Stack empty.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1.ThrowForEmptyStack()
   at System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1.Pop()
   at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.OnRestorePreviousScope()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.RestorePreviousScope()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()
   at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop)
   at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input)
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper()
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc()
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)

This is, I think, an example of the following issues:

Concurrently invoking a ScriptBlock in two runspaces causes InvalidOperationException and pwsh.exe termination #7626
Engine event processing bypasses "ShouldQueueAndProcessInExecutionThread" causing state corruption and crash due to Runspace affinity #4003

Those issues are now six and seven years old.  Around that time Jason Shirk made the following comment about what looks to me like a similar manifestation:

Scriptblocks have runspace affinity. ...I think this is an architectural flaw, but it's not easy to fix without requiring locks throughout the engine.

I am assuming that this problem is unlikely to be resolved by the PowerShell engine anytime soon.  I'm happy to work around this limitation wherever I have multiple Runspaces.  But that internal stacktrace error is rather unhelpful at finding where the offending ScriptBlock has arisen from.
Instead I would like to be able to guard against invoking such a ScriptBlock by detecting it beforehand so that I can raise an actionable error.  With that error message the underlying bug can be tracked down.  Without that error message, all I know is that some scriptblock, anywhere in the entire process, was invoked in a Runspace to which it does not belong.
In other words I would like to be able to write a statement like
Assert-ScriptBlockAffinity -CurrentOrNoRunspace -ScriptBlock $arg1.ScriptBlock

which would output something like
ScriptBlockAffinityException: C:\demo.ps1:1
Line |
   1 |  Assert-ScriptBlockAffinity -CurrentOrNoRunspace -ScriptBlock $arg1.ScriptBlockwith a …
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | ScriptBlock detected in Runspace Id 1 with affinity to a different Runspace.

Such an error would give me at least the Runspace Id and source code location which would go a long way to narrowing in on the culprit.
How can I detect such an offending ScriptBlock?
Ideally this could be done with public APIs, but considering this should really only arise during development, an implementation using private APIs would be nearly as useful, I think.

Indeed, it is safe to invoke [scriptblock] instances if and only if:

either: they are bound to the same runspace as the caller  (binding to the caller's runspace happens when you use script block literals ({ ... })

or: they are unbound (as happens when you use [scriptblock]::Create('<source-code>') or { ... }.Ast.GetScriptBlock()), in which case they can be safely invoked from any runspace.


Unfortunately, there are no public APIs to determine a given script block's runspace affinity, if any, but you can solve the problem via non-public APIs, using .NET reflection, which comes with the usual caveat:

Non-public APIs aren't meant to be called from the outside, and are subject to change without notice.

In the case at hand, there are unfortunately three non-public members that must be accessed.


The following custom function, Assert-Invokable, asserts that a given [scriptblock] instance can be safely invoked by the caller, and reports a statement-terminating error (exception) otherwise.
function Assert-Invokable {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [scriptblock] $ScriptBlock
  )
 
  # Get the runspace associated with the given script block, if any.
  $rs = & {
    # Binding flags for finding non-public instance members via reflection.
    $bindingFlags = [System.Reflection.BindingFlags] 'NonPublic, Instance'
    
    # Get the non-public [System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal] instance
    # associated with the script block, via the non-public .SessionStateInternal property.
    $ssInternal = 
      [scriptblock].GetProperty('SessionStateInternal', $bindingFlags).GetValue($ScriptBlock)

    if ($ssInternal) {
      # From the [System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal] instance,
      # obtain the associated non-public [System.Management.Automation.ExecutionContext] instance.
      # via the non-public .ExecutionContext property.
      $ec = 
        $ssInternal.GetType().GetProperty('ExecutionContext', $bindingFlags).GetValue($ssInternal)
      
      # From the [System.Management.Automation.ExecutionContext] instance, obtain the associated
      # [runspace] instance (which itself is public), via the non-public .CurrentRunspace property.
      ($rs = $ec.GetType().GetProperty('CurrentRunspace', $bindingFlags).GetValue($ec))
      Write-Verbose ('Script block is bound to runspace {0} ({1})' -f $rs.Name, $rs.Id)
    }
    else {
      # Implies that the given script is *unbound*, i.e. doesn't have any
      # runspace affinity.
      Write-Verbose 'Script block is unbound.'
    }    
  }

  # $rs being $null implies that the script block is *unbound*, which means that
  # it can be invoked from *any* runspace; if it is *bound*, it can only be safely
  # invoked if it is bound to the *caller's* runspace.
  if (-not ($null -eq $rs -or $rs -eq [runspace]::DefaultRunspace)) {
    $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError(
      [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]::new(
        [System.ArgumentException]::new(('Cannot call the given script block from runsapce {0} ({1}), because it is bound to a different one, {2} ({3})' -f [runspace]::DefaultRunspace.Name, [runspace]::DefaultRunspace.Id, $rs.Name, $rs.Id)),
        'ScriptBlockRunspaceMismatch',
        [System.Management.Automation.ErrorCategory]::InvalidArgument,
        $ScriptBlock
      )
    )
  }

}

Note:

[runspace]::DefaultRunspace uses thread-local storage to report the caller's own runspace.


Thank you @mklement0.  FWIW, I tested this approach by comparing the values of $rs produced across all combinations of default and runspaces from global and module scriptblocks arising from two different runspaces.  Indeed all values of $rs from all scriptblocks arising from a single runspace are the same object.  And, of course, the default runspace of the two runspaces differs.  So, if I'm correctly understanding how PowerShell is structured, this appears to work for all scenarios.

Glad to hear it, @alx9r. Note that what Santiago implemented is a more restrictive test: it tests whether the caller and the script block are bound to the same session state (scope domain), so that, for instance, the assertion fails for a script block bound to the non-module scope domain that is examined in a module function - even though they're both in the same runspace.

FWIW, I measured the performance penalty of this check.  A single isolated call to Assert-Invokable with a bound scriptblock  imposes a penalty on the order of 500us on this computer.  10000 of the same calls imposes a penalty on the order of 100us each.  This seems like a small price to pay for the error reporting improvement.

I proposed that this check be built into the PowerShell engine in this github issue.

A ScriptBlock is always bound to the runspace it was instantiated on, you shouldn't even attempt to guard against invoking such a ScriptBlock by detecting it beforehand instead, if you're going to invoke it in a different runspace strip it from its runspace affinity first by creating a new one via .Ast.GetScriptBlock():
foreach ($i in 1..100) {
    $sb = { 'bound_to_parent_runspace' }
    . $sb | Out-Null

    1..2 | ForEach-Object {
        $startThreadJobSplat = @{
            ArgumentList = [pscustomobject]@{ ScriptBlock = $sb.Ast.GetScriptBlock() }
            ScriptBlock  = {
                param($arg1)
                'child_runspace'
                . $arg1.ScriptBlock
            }
        }

        Start-ThreadJob @startThreadJobSplat |
            Receive-Job -Wait -ErrorAction Stop
    }
}

A few related answers that go over this issue:

Piping to Where-Object and Foreach.Object not working in module delayed loaded in $Profile
How to pass $_ ($PSItem) in a ScriptBlock
Foreach-Object -Parallel returning "The term 'write-host' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program"


If you want to test if a script block was created in the current session you can use reflection to get the scriptblock's SessionStateInternal and the test reference equality against the passed-in execution context:
function Assert-ScriptBlockAffinity {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [scriptblock] $ScriptBlock,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [System.Management.Automation.EngineIntrinsics] $Context
    )

    $prop = [scriptblock].GetProperty(
        'SessionStateInternal',
        [System.Reflection.BindingFlags] 'NonPublic, Instance')
    $state = $prop.GetValue($ScriptBlock, $null)

    [object]::ReferenceEquals($Context.SessionState.Applications, $state.Applications) -and
    [object]::ReferenceEquals($Context.SessionState.Scripts, $state.Scripts)
}

Then if you pass-in a scriptblock created in the current session it returns true:
Assert-ScriptBlockAffinity { 123 } $ExecutionContext
# true

Else, if the scriptblock was created in a different runspace, returns false:
$sb = [powershell]::Create([System.Management.Automation.RunspaceMode]::NewRunspace).
    AddScript('{ 123 }').Invoke()[0]

Assert-ScriptBlockAffinity $sb $ExecutionContext
# false

Same if you strip it from runspace affinity as pointed up in the above:
Assert-ScriptBlockAffinity { 123 }.Ast.GetScriptBlock() $ExecutionContext
# false


_"...you shouldn't even attempt to guard against invoking such a ScriptBlock..."  I don't follow this line of reasoning.  Suppose I encounter the stack trace in my OP?  How do I, as a developer responsible for that occurrence, find the offending scriptblock?  Obviously there is something wrong about my code that such a scriptblock got invoked.  But how do I find that scriptblock when the error message reveals nothing other than that PowerShell crashed?  The point of detecting such an offending scriptblock is so that the developer can find the offender and correct the problem.

"A ScriptBlock is always bound to the runspace it was instantiated on..."  I'm fairly confident this is not true in some cases.  As far as I have been able to establish, "...scriptblocks created via [ScriptBlock]::Create are not bound to a runspace until they are first invoked.".  I suspect the same applies to {}.Ast.GetScriptBlock().

@alx9r I can add a further evaluation that probes what you want but I really dont know what is not clear already about this answer, you shouldn't attempt to invoke a scriptblock in a different runspace than the one it was created before stripping its runspace affinity. The error message isn't clear I agree with that but there is nothing we can do in a stack overflow answer about it.

@alx9r added the function you were asking for, no idea how that can be useful since you the developer have full control of the runspace you created and know exactly what arguments are being passed to it...

"...you the developer have full control of the runspace you created and know exactly what arguments are being passed to it..."  I think this is where our viewpoints differ.  Some code for which I am responsible I didn't write myself.  Other code I did write myself but surely contains errors I have not yet corrected.  Some such errors have, from time to time, led to the fatal error in my OP.

@alx9r yeah well idk what to tell or what you're expecting for an answer to your question. A simple argument check for is ScriptBlock would be the proper way to handle this instead of trying to work around it. That's what ForEach-Object -Parallel does...

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
